# Problemas con filtros al pulsar un botón - PHP y Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Hola tengo un problema con algo que se me está resistiendo, seguramente sea muy fácil, pero mi inexperiencia me lo complica.
Estoy trabajando con PHP y lo que tengo que hacer realizarlo con JQuery.

Es lo siguiente:

Tengo una pantalla con HTML se divide en dos partes: Dos campos de filtros y un botón y abajo el resto del cuerpo con más filtros, datatable, etc

El segundo  que es el resto del cuerpo, lo tengo oculto con la clase hide, para que no se muestre al cargar la pantalla.

La cosa es que una vez que yo rellene los dos filtros (el segundo puede no ser necesario ya que es un combo que se activa o no dependiendo del primero) debe salir el resto del cuerpo al pulsar el botón. Si al rellenar el primer filtro no necesita del segundo (este se mantendrá oculto), si pulso el botón salga el resto del cuerpo y si necesita del segundo (aparecerá ya que es un combo) que no salga el resto del cuerpo al pulsar el botón hasta tener el segundo relleno también.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 m-b-15 p-l-0">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
            <label for="nombreDocumento">Tipo de Entidad</label>
            <select id="tipoEntidad" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Seleccione Entidad</option>
                @foreach($listTipoEntidades as $entidad)
                    <option value="{{$entidad->id_entidad}}" data-requiere-valor="{{$entidad->flag_requiere_valor}}">{{$entidad->desc_entidad}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6 hide" id="filtroCliente">
            <label for="filtroClientes">Cliente</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filtroClientes" placeholder="CLIENTE 1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <button class="btn btn-primary m-t-24" id="btnVerDocumentos">Ver Documentos</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 p-5">
    <div id="contenidoVerDocumentos" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 hide">
       Aquí va el resto de filtros, ect...
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Se registran los eventos de los botones
    $('#btnVerDocumentos').onclick(function(event){
        var entidadSeleccionada = $(this).val();
        event.preventDefault();
        if(entidadSeleccionada != ''){
            $('#contenidoVerDocumentos').removeClass('hide');
        }
 });
```

Lo que tengo en Jquery es una prueba que no me ha funcionado.

Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y ayuda.

Comment: Podrías agregar el código

Comment: O alguna foto para que sea más visual

Comment: Segun entiendo lo que quieres hacer es que cuando seleccione el primero o bien el segundo y se presione el boton aparezca el cuerpo? $('#boton').onclick(function(event){
  event.preventDefault(); 
  if (valicaciondeloscampos){
  $('#cuerpo').show();  
 
  }
  
});

Comment: es preferible que insertes el código en la pregunta en vez de una caputa de pantalla del código

Comment: Buenas a todos y muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda, es mi primera pregunta y no sabía bien como iba el tema de insertar código y tal, pero ya he editado la pregunta. @oegpyg he intentado hacer algo así como lo que me decías pero no me funciona

Comment: He añadido el código @Leonel

Comment: aplica un console.log(entidadSeleccionada ), para ver si selecciona los datos el $(this).value

Comment: @Leonel parece que no selecciona los datos porque me dice que entidadSeleccionada no está definida

Comment: intenta cambiando el entidadSeleccionada != '', por if (entidadSeleccionada != null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espero que esto sea lo que necesitas

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Se registran los eventos de los botones
    $('#contenidoVerDocumentos').hide(); 
    $('#tipoEntidad').on('change', function(){
        if($(this).val() == ''){
            $('#contenidoVerDocumentos').hide();
        }
    });
    $('#btnVerDocumentos').on('click', function(event){
        var entidadSeleccionada = $('#tipoEntidad').val();
        event.preventDefault();
        var elem = $('#contenidoVerDocumentos');
        if(entidadSeleccionada != ''){
            elem.text(' Elemento seleccionado: '+ entidadSeleccionada );
            elem.show();
        }else{
            elem.hide();
            alert('No ha seleccionado ninguna opcion');
        }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 m-b-15 p-l-0">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
            <label for="nombreDocumento">Tipo de Entidad</label>
            <select id="tipoEntidad" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Seleccione Entidad</option>
               
                    <option value="1" data-requiere-valor="">1</option>
               
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6 hidden-xl-down" id="filtroCliente">
            <label for="filtroClientes">Cliente</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filtroClientes" placeholder="CLIENTE 1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <button class="btn btn-primary m-t-24" id="btnVerDocumentos">Ver Documentos</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 p-5">
    <div id="contenidoVerDocumentos" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
       Aquí va el resto de filtros, ect...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: si, así,aunque el else no me lo pilla,no vuelve a aplicar el hide si está vacío el filtro:
    $('#contenidoVerDocumentos').hide(); 
    $('#btnVerDocumentos').on('click', function(event){
        var entidadSeleccionada = $('#tipoEntidad').val();
        event.preventDefault();
        if(entidadSeleccionada != ''){
            $('#contenidoVerDocumentos').show(); 
        } else {
            $('#contenidoVerDocumentos').hide(); 
        }
    });
¿como podría meter el segundo filtro para que en caso de que se active no salga el cuerpo hasta que esté relleno?Muchas gracias

Comment: @eogpyg funciona el alert y el else que yo puse, la cosa es que funcionan cuando quito lo que haya seleccionado, no selecciono nada, pero para que funcione tengo que volver a hacer click en el botón. La cosa sería que sin necesidad de hacer click el cuerpo desapareciera, al quitar la selección y estar el campo vacío. Muchas gracias una vez más, me estás ayudando mucho

Comment: ahi te modifique como quieres

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda